# mariadb saves all INSERT information from php twice

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

I dont know how to explain that,but my MariaDB start inserting the values from php twice on PDO,even if i dont write it.

that the code what i make to insert values:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$name = trim($name);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$email = trim($email);
$password = password_hash($_REQUEST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$password = trim($password);
$country = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'country',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$country = trim($country);
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'city',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$city = trim($city);
if(!mb_strlen($name) > 3){
  $error['name'] = 'Your name is wrong';
}if(!$email){
 $error['email'] = 'Your email is wrong';
}if(!$password > 6){
 $error['password'] = 'Please try again,your password should be more 
 than 6 chars length';
}if(!strlen($country) > 3){
 $error['country'] = 'Your country is less than 3 chars length,please 
 try again';
}if(!strlen($city) > 3){
  $error['city'] = 'Your city name is less than 3 chars length,please 
try again';
}
if($name && $email && $password && $country && $city){
     $myPdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',USER,PASS);
     $query = "INSERT INTO users 
     VALUES(null,'$name','$email','$password','$country','$city')";
     $errorPdo = $myPdo-->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
     $prepareSql = $myPdo->prepare($query);
     $prepareSql->execute();
     var_dump($prepareSql->execute());
 }
}
```

and that what i get from database:

```
MariaDB [blog]> SELECT * FROM users;
1 | Alexandr | alexandr@mail.com | $2y$10$wR0PN3o2iZo/H5G60dSUwOz7mZmi6.RihVrFhZjRcCYomR.3Ttqga | Israel  | Holon
2 | Alexandr | alexandr@mail.com | $2y$10$wR0PN3o2iZo/H5G60dSUwOz7mZmi6.RihVrFhZjRcCYomR.3Ttqga | Israel  | Holon
```

Can You please explain me why is that?
I cant find an answer,and please dont minus me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$preparSql->execute()` twice in your code.

```
$prepareSql->execute();
var_dump($prepareSql->execute());
```

Remove one of those and it will only be inserted once.

Comment: @AlexandrLamdan - If you want the result value from `execute`, grab it into a variable, _then_ var_dump it.